# How to debug snapin, property pages in mmc?

Tags: vb6, mmc, snap-in

I am new to snapin and property pages.

I have a source code that is developed in Visual basic 6.0 of snapin(userControl) and property pages that are referenced in snapin. These will be run in mmc. Now how can i debug this snapin and property pages by adding in mmc.

Answer (score 1):

This post is very old but if it can help some one.

To debug a snapin, in the VB6 Editor, go to `Project > Property of ...`

Then, in the debugging tab, choose the third option "Start a programm" and type in `mmc` or the full path to `mmc.exe` (for me it was `C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe`).

When you try to run you project, an MMC window will show up and you can go to `File > Add Component ...` and choose your snap-in project. Pay attention that 2 component coresponding to your project can be present. You have to try both with a breakpoint in your code to know witch one is debug one.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If some one know how to load automaticaly the project snap-in in mmc when running the project, it should be perfect !

Comment: Definitely very old now, but still useful. I've come across situation where some old legacy VB6 mmc code needs to be changed as the above helped, and I found further to Emrys Myrooin reply above, what I did was had the full path to my MSC following the call to the mmc.exe,   eg.   C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe D:\Apps\myApp\mySnapIn.msc    this then loaded automatically the project snap-in.